# Timer delay in VBA-powerpoint

Tags: vba, object, powerpoint, pause

I am developping bingo application in powerpoint with a sound (bingo draw) connected to a object in the ppt. The bingo randomizer is also connected to the same object, and therefore, the random number generator has to pause for 7 sec until the sounds has played. Unfortunately my code with pause does not show a new generated number anymore while without the pause it works. So it works if i exclude the:

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:07")
```

From:

```
Sub UpdateRandomNumber(oSh As Shape)
Dim X As Long
'Make the shape’s text a random number
'X or less
'Change 50 below to any number you’d like:
X = 50


oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CStr(Random(X))
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:07")
'Now force PPT to go to the slide again (ie, to redraw it) so that
'the changed text appears:
SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex)

End Sub

Function Random(High As Long) As Long

'Function Random(InArray() As Variant) 'new
'Generates a random number less than or equal to
'the value passed in High
Randomize
Random = Int((High * Rnd) + 1)

End Function
```

ps. if someone knows how to change the random generator to draw non-duplicates that would be a great addition

[bingo in ptt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTx1P.jpg)

Comment: Always choose Debug | Compile before running your code. Saves a lot of head-scratching. In this case, it'd point out that there's no Application.Wait method in PowerPoint. Normally you'd see a compile error when you tried to run the code, but when you're in SlideShow view, PPT simply swallows/doesn't display any errors. If your code won't compile, PPT ignores it. Try using the Windows SLEEP api call instead. Example on my PPT FAQ page here:  Put your macro to Sleep
https://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00466_Put_your_macro_to_Sleep.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If insert the "Private Declare Sub ...." statement i get: compile error: the code in this project must be updated for use of 64-bit systems". When i fix this it works! great thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that reminder.  I'll update the code on that page to include a 64-bit option.

Answer (score 1):

Try a DoEvents loop instead. Place this declaration at the top of the module:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As LongPtr
```

Then add this sub:

```
Sub Pause(Length As LongPtr)
    Dim NowTime As LongPtr
    Dim EndTime As LongPtr

    EndTime = GetTickCount + (Length * 1000)
    Do
        NowTime = GetTickCount
        DoEvents
    Loop Until NowTime >= EndTime
End Sub
```

Then replace the Wait statement with something like this:

```
Pause(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunaltely it does not work yet. If i apply it with the #'s then there is still no pause and if i apply it without the #'s then the number does not change anymore in de ppt slide.

The "Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long" in the else statement that you subbested appears in red. Is that as it is supposed to be? Do you understand what should be changed?

Comment: Sorry, you're using 64-bit Office, so I changed the Longs to LongPtrs. I've also simplified the declaration. This will run on Office 2010 or later without the conditional compilation.